# Comments on election nominations aren't linked in user profile

Tags: bug, comments, election

User comments on the [2013 Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) page are not linked to on profile pages.
Consider, for example, Kolink's [recent activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink?tab=activity).

Screenshot:

[image]

The two middle comments, for example, was made on the election page. Yet they don't show the source.

Comment: @Bart - good find. Unfortunately the issue hasn't been resolved even though it was originally reported in June.